# Import project's subpackages in Python

Tags: python, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

i'm experimenting with DDD in Python so i've decided to implement a toy project.

I've created different directories in other to separate shared concepts from specific bounded contexts concepts.

As i try to import these files, i'm facing a `No module named error` exceptions

For example, with this project structure:

```
.
└── src/
    ├── Book/
    │   ├── application
    │   ├── domain/
    │   │   ├── Book.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── infrastructure
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── Shared/
        ├── application
        ├── domain/
        │   ├── Properties/
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
        │   │   └── UuidProperty.py
        │   ├── ValueObjects/
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
        │   │   └── BookId.py
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── infrastructure
```

On `src/Book/domain/Book.py` i have:

```py
from Shared.domain.ValueObjects.BookId import BookId


class Book:
    bookId: BookId
    pages: int
```

As i've seen in other answer (pretty old ones) it can be fixed by adding these folders to `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` like `sys.path.insert(*path to file*)` but i'm wondering if there is a more *pythonic* way to achieve that.

I've also tried to add an `__init__.py` file to src and import as `from src.Shared.domain.ValueObjects.BookId import BookId` but none of previous attempts worked for me

On other repos i've saw that they use `setuptools` to install the `src` package in order to import it at unit tests (i cant either import them at tests), but i don't know if that is recommended or would work inside package imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is facing the same issue as me, i managed to import subpackages and the full package in tests directory.

Just include, in each subpackage, an `__init__.py` file, and inside the package/subpackages, use relative imports (it looses semantic of imports, when we know where each imports comes from by absolute path from root directory, but works)

```py
from ..Properties import UuidProperty

# inside __init__.py of Properties directory

from .UuidProperty import UuidProperty
```

And, by including an `__init__.py` inside `src/` we could import them at tests directory like

```py
from src.Book.domain import Book
```

Hope this helps someone!